# php substr with special characters like German Umlaute ä,ö and ü

Tags: php

I would like to crop a text string to three characters. Doing so, using `$name_short = substr($name, 0, 3);` works great. But as so as the text contains German Umlaute like ä,ö or ü within the first three characters, **Würzburg** for example is shortened to **W&u**. Using `$name_short = substr(html_entity_decode($name), 0, 3);` works nicely and keeps the Umlaute, but the result is not **Wür** (for Würzburg), but **Wü**. I have no idea how to **if/else** my code correctly to check if there are Umlaute or other special characters from other languages within the first three characters.

So I could crop the string to 4 characters if special characters are found, otherwise to 3.

**This made it work:**

```
$name = html_entity_decode($name);
$name_short = mb_substr($name, 0, 3);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `html_entity_decode()` has nothing to do with this, you want to take care to understand how unicode (UTF) works in your setup though and how to take advantage of the "multibyte string functions" php offers. There is an official documentation about that. Makes sense to read into the topic...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try mb_substr() instead of substr() like below:

```
        $name = "Würzburg";
        $name_short = mb_substr($name, 0, 3);
```

Comment: This works as you wrote. But "Würzburg" comes from a variable and then the result still is "W&U".

Comment: Hi, it is the because of you might be using older version of php ( less then 5.6 ). It works on php 5.6 and php 7.0.

Answer (score 2):

This may be an issue of encoding...

You can try `mb_substr($name,0,3,'UTF-8');`

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact those special characters (such as ä, ö, ü, œ and others) use more than one byte. So the result you get by using `substr()` is technically correct as it returns a 3-byte long string.

Using the multibyte version of the function should fix that problem: 
`$name_short = mb_substr($name, 0, 3);`

Also, as @arkascha mentioned, using `html_entity_decode()` will not help you in your situation as it doesn't affect special characters.

`mb_substr` doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php